# Can a Controller method returning void produce JSON?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Normally to return JSON from my Controllers methods, I add a `@ResponseBody` annotation and I let Jackson to map my returned object as JSON. No problem here.

However in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039928/requestmapping-not-working), the OP says *"my other methods that use @RequestMapping return void, and I can still get JSON from them through ajax"*.

I was wondering how's that possible? I've no reason to doubt, that he's indeed doing that, so I would like to know how to do that, for the sake of curiosity and enhancing my Spring understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write directly to the HttpServletResponse:

```
@ResponseBody
public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String json = "{\"Hello\": \"World\"}";
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(json);
}
```

Comment: right, I should have thought about it, thank you. seems an inferior choice though. -- In this case you don't need `@ResponseBody`, from [the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) *"If the method is annotated with @ResponseBody, the return type is written to the response HTTP body. The return value will be converted to the declared method argument type using HttpMessageConverters"*

Comment: Yeah, personally I don't know why you'd want to do it this way... I never have in production!  I just know it's possible.